# 2-d graph with two different axis showing different min and max MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphing

I have the graph below I need to create two different x-axis.  The unique part of this problem is where the min and max values need to be located.  The range for is 0-100 for both, however the 100% value on the second x-axis needs to be where the 50% value is on the first.  See the picture for clarification.  The red is what I need to add using MATLAB.

I did a lot of looking and while it's very simple to put two different axis on one graph, I couldn't find a solution for this particular problem.  I'd like this to be done in the code and not plot tools.

[image]

Comment: have you looked at [this tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/graph-with-multiple-x-axes-and-y-axes.html)?

Comment: yes. It does a very good just of telling how to put multiple axis on a graph, but does not address the problem I presented. I realized I could make the scale on the second axis 0-200, however this gives the reader the assumption that there could be values  above 100, which is not possible.

Comment: You may play with the `'XTicks'` and `'XTicksLabels'` of the second axis.

Comment: I've looked at that too. Maybe it could do what I'm after, but I'm not seeing it. It seems to me that XTicks can only change the distance between labels and not the total distance it would run along the axis.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like you have tried a lot of things. if you can add to your post a short description (possibly some code) can help others provide better answers to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
% dummy data
y = 1:80; 
x1 = 100*sin( 4*pi*y/80 ).^2 ;  
x2 = 100*cos( 5*pi*y/80).^2;
```

Plot the first line

```
figure; 
line( x1, y, 'Color', 'b', 'LineWidth', 2 );
```

Get position and size of first plot

```
haxes1 = gca; 
haxes1_pos = get(haxes1,'Position');
```

set the 100% of second plot to 50% of first ("tweaking" the width of the axis)

```
haxes1_pos(3) = haxes1_pos(3)/2; 
haxes2 = axes('Position',haxes1_pos,'XAxisLocation','top','Color','none','XColor','r');
```

Plot the second line

```
line( x2, y, 'Color', 'k', 'LineWidth',2,'Parent',haxes2);
```

And this is what you get
[image]

Comment: Exactly.  Thank you.  This is the part of the code I needed that the tutorial you linked earlier didn't have:
haxes1_pos(3) = haxes1_pos(3)/2; 

another thing though.  When I run your code I get the following error:

Attempt to call constructor axes with incorrect letter case.

I'm not modifying it for my use, that is running the exact code you posted.  I'm assuming by the graph you show it works for you.

Comment: @user3753314 worked for me R2009a. try removing the `'Color'` and `'XColor'` arguments of `axes`.

Comment: @user3753314 first, try onlt `haxes2 = axes('Position', haxes1_pos);` this is the critical part. if this works you can try setting the other properties later.